# Calling provider context inside initState

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to obtain a value from database in the initState method. So I try to access the value by calling a function using Provider.of(context) method. However, I am getting the following error:

````
 E/flutter ( 6424): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<RestaurantTimings> above this MyApp Widget
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424): This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
E/flutter ( 6424): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
E/flutter ( 6424):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   Make sure that MyApp is under your MultiProvider/Provider<RestaurantTimings>.
E/flutter ( 6424):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   For example, instead of:
E/flutter ( 6424):   For example, instead of:
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   ```
E/flutter ( 6424):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter ( 6424):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter ( 6424):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter ( 6424):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
E/flutter ( 6424):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
E/flutter ( 6424):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
E/flutter ( 6424):     ),
E/flutter ( 6424):   }
E/flutter ( 6424):   ```
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   consider using `builder` like so:
E/flutter ( 6424):
E/flutter ( 6424):   ```
E/flutter ( 6424):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
E/flutter ( 6424):     return Provider<Example>(
E/flutter ( 6424):       create: (_) => Example(),
E/flutter ( 6424):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
E/flutter ( 6424):       builder: (context) {
E/flutter ( 6424):         // No longer throws
E/flutter ( 6424):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
E/flutter ( 6424):       }
E/flutter ( 6424):     ),
E/flutter ( 6424):   }
````

Here's my code:

```
Future<void> main() async { 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isLoading = false;
  var isOpen = false; 
  ClosingOpeningHours _timing;
  
  void initState(){ 
    super.initState();
    _getTimingOrClosing();
  }
  
  _getTimingOrClosing() async{ 
    _timing =  await Provider.of<RestaurantTimings>(context, listen: false)
                                   .fetchTiming();
    print('Start close in main ' + _timing.startClose); 
  }
   Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
           setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
  });
    print('Inside initPackageInfo'); 
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }
 
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return !(_isLoading)?MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          create:null,
          update:(ctx,auth, previousProducts) => Products(auth.token, 
          
        auth.userId)), 
         
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Cart(),
        ),
        
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ColorChanger(),
        ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth,RestaurantTimings>(
          create:null,
         update:(ctx,auth, previousTimings) => RestaurantTimings(auth.token)),
    ],

    //The consumer ensures that the material app gets built whenever Auth object changes
        child: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) => 
          MaterialApp( 
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,    
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
           textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
            bodyColor: Colors.black,
            displayColor: Colors.black,
            ),
          primaryColor:  Colors.white,
          accentColor:  Color(0xFFF2AD18),
          fontFamily: 'Muli',
        ),
        home:      
             auth.isAuth && !isopen ? StoreTimings(): auth.isAuth && isopen?
        CategoriesScreen()
         : FutureBuilder(
                      future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                      builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                          authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting
                              ?  Center(
                                    child: Loading(),
                                )
                              : LoginPage(),
        ),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName:(ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        }
      ),
        ) 
    ):Center(child:Loading());
  }
}
```

The specific code which throws this error is:

```
_timing =  await Provider.of<RestaurantTimings>(context, listen: false)
                                   .fetchTiming();
```

If you look at my code, you will see that I have already listed `RestaurantTiming` in the multiprovider. I really need to run this before the main UI builds.

Comment: I need the authtoken to be able to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that context is not available during initState, as the Widget tree has not been built yet (and hence there is no context).

A workaround is to do the same job in `didChangeDependencies`, which runs after initState and has access to context.

To avoid fetching your data every time `didChangeDependencies` runs, you can create a private class property called `_isInit` set initially to true. Once `didChangeDependencies` runs for the first time it will be set to false, and our fetching code won't run again.

Here is the code:

```
var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      _getTimingOrClosing();
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

**EDIT:**
After more careful inspection, I see the issue in your code. You are calling Provider in `initState` BUT your MultiProvider is in your Widget build. As `initState` runs before Build method, there is no Provider "above" the place you're calling it from.
I would suggest moving your main code into another Widget which has MultiProvider as an ancestor.

Pseudo-code that you can follow and fine-tune to your requirements:

```dart
Future<void> main () async{
runApp(MyHomeApp());
}

class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(){
      return MultiProvider(
        providers:[....],//Your providers here
        child: MyApp(),
      );
    }
}
```

For MyApp Widget just remove the MultiProvider and keep everything else the same.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isLoading = false;
  var isOpen = false; 
  ClosingOpeningHours? _timing;
  
  void initState(){ 
    super.initState();
    _getTimingOrClosing();
  }
  
  _getTimingOrClosing() async{ 
    _timing =  await Provider.of<RestaurantTimings>(context, listen: false)
                                   .fetchTiming();
    print('Start close in main ' + _timing.startClose); 
  }
  
  
   Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
           setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
  });
    print('Inside initPackageInfo'); 
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }
 
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return !(_isLoading)?Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) => 
      MaterialApp( 
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,    
    title: 'MyApp',
    theme: ThemeData(
       textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
        bodyColor: Colors.black,
        displayColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      primaryColor:  Colors.white,
      accentColor:  Color(0xFFF2AD18),
      fontFamily: 'Muli',
    ),
    home:      
         auth.isAuth && !isopen ? StoreTimings(): auth.isAuth && isopen?
    CategoriesScreen()
     : FutureBuilder(
                  future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                  builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                      authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting
                          ?  Center(
                                child: Loading(),
                            )
                          : LoginPage(),
    ),
    routes: {
      ProductDetailScreen.routeName:(ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
    }
      ),
    ):Center(child:Loading());
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure it is work, but would you mind to try like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _getTimingOrClosing();
    });
  }
```